# autoreconf: command not found in Cygwin on Windows

Tags: windows, compilation, cygwin

I'm trying to compile the `nDPI` library in using Cygwin on Windows. When I try to run `autogen.sh` file I get the following error

> ./autogen.sh: line 5: autoreconf: command not found

I've been looking around now for four days to compile this `nDPI` library on Windows, and I DO NEED to compile it on Windows.

1. How do I compile this library on Windows?, OR
2. Is there a link that actually works and I can follow their steps to compile this library?

Here is the `autogen.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

/bin/rm -f configure config.h config.h.in src/lib/Makefile.in
autoreconf -ivf
./configure
```

Comment: @yanivx I shared the autogen.sh in the EDIT section

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try install `autoconf`, `automake` and `libtool`. It's under `Devel` of the Cygwin setup program.

Answer (score 4):

To build MSYS tools, you should use the autotools provided in the MSYS System Builder package:

http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435&package_id=227249

`autoconf-2.61-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2 
automake-1.10-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2 
libtool1.5-1.5.25a-20070701-MSYS-1.0.11-1.tar.bz2`

Unpack them to the same location you extracted msys package.

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken. It redirects to a place that seems to be far removed from the intended.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to first solve the errors, since they indicate that you are lacking of some of the essential libraries. For example, the `autoconf` library...

If you are using Cygwin, you can get `apt-cyg` by:

```
lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

After that, you can use `apt-cyg install xxx` to install the lacking libraries.